# how to find a folder based on creation time

Tags: scripts, backup, cron

I would like to write a small script that:

1. finds the creation date/time of a folder on a server that creates a backup folder every two days  with the date as 2016 04 22 as folder name
2. remove the  whole folder using rm so i can get the disk space back free.
3. then,this script should run on a regular basis with some cron.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I like to make backups using a bash script like this

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`

tar -jcvf /home/backup/myfiles-$DATE.tBz2 dirtobackup1 dirtoback2

If you want you can run something like this to clean it up 
find /home/backup/ -ctime +2 -exec rm {} \;

This has a number of advantages over what you are asking.  Backups are compressed and in files.  Since they are in files you can do a "rm" instead of a "rm -rf" which can go so very wrong in scripts

After you get the script to work just put it in /etc/cron.daily to run every day.

Comment: so far i managed to do it.so now,what if i need to delete folder with spaces in the name,or other special characters?

Comment: Be careful with "rm -rf" because it can go wrong.  If you can remove the file contents and then use rmdir it is safer.  Find will take care of spaces for you.  If you get the name some other way you will probably want to use quotes around it.   this will remove a directory ending in dir  even with a space:       find ./ -name "*dir" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: well...here is the command that i use...
cd /home/errikos/1 && ls -t1 /home/errikos/1 | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -r

Comment: this should something like what you want for directories over two days old.  You can replace "rm -r" with echo for testing.  the command:  find /home/errikos/1/ -type d -ctime +2 -exec rm -r {} \;

Comment: tested this command,something i'm missing?? no folders deleted...
i used find /home/errikos/1/ -type d -ctime +2 -exec rm -r {} \; and as folder names "untitle folder" and  "1 folder - test"

Comment: run just find /home/errikos/1/ -type d  to confirm it's finding all folders.  then run  find /home/errikos/1/ -type d -ctime +1  to see what has change over a day ago.   My guess is the folder are to new to show up. .